# How do I get the parent value from child in Firebase real time database?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I am trying to develop a school related app. Here is the picture of my database. In my code I have the schoolEmail as a string (i.e String email = iisd@gmail.com). I want to use this string to know to which school does this email belong to (IISD in this case) I want to get this value as String.

**Please see this picture**

[image][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IXcPf.png)

And Here is my code

```
public class HomeScreen extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView schoolName,schoolEmail,schoolPhone,schoolAddress;
    Button logoutSchool;
    DatabaseReference databaseReference;
    String email;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home_screen);
        schoolName = findViewById(R.id.schoolName);
        schoolEmail = findViewById(R.id.schoolEmail);
        schoolPhone = findViewById(R.id.schoolPhone);
        schoolAddress = findViewById(R.id.schoolAddress);
        logoutSchool = findViewById(R.id.loginSchool);
        databaseReference =         FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
        email = "iisd@gmail.com";

        databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                // This method is called once with the initial value and again
                // whenever data at this location is updated.
                DataSnapshot dataSnapshot1 = dataSnapshot.getChildren();
                String value = dataSnapshot.child("Schools").getKey();

                Toast.makeText(HomeScreen.this, value, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {

            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: so you want IISD to be dependent upon the school, and under that, it will have certain information?

Comment: The "School" will remain the same and all the schools are added into it yes. I want to add more schools and each one will have an email, so I want to use this email to get the school name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
        databaseReference.child("Schools").orderByChild("schoolEmail").equalTo("iisd@gmail.com").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                    String value = ds.getKey();
                    Toast.makeText(HomeScreen.this, value, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {
                throw databaseError.toException();
            }
        });
```

Here your reference is at node `Schools`, then you use a query `orderByChild("schoolEmail").equalTo("iisd@gmail.com")` to check if schoolEmail = email_value, then using for loop you can get the key.